# Need responsive design for div inside div

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Hi I am new to Html and I want to design div inside a div in responsive website.

**UPDATE:** I want this design only in `HTML/CSS` not in `Javascript` or `Jquery`.

Below image can make clear about the design. I am unable to achieve this. Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Thanx in advance :)

Comment: Have you included the responsive css ?

Comment: So `left div` and `right div` magically disappear on mobile? I think you need to rethink the layout of your page, because there is no way that the content of grouping containers can be intertwined as per your example.

Comment: I want that left div and right div merge into a single div on mobile device. Is it achievable?

Comment: you can use bootstrap for that..but in mobile the order would be div1,div2,div3,div a,b,c

Comment: I doubt that there is a pure css solution for "zipping" the contents of two containers, but everything is possible with javascript.

Comment: @Pranav We cant change the order of the div1, div a, div 2, div b..

Comment: can you use bootstrap?

Comment: take a look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it but you may have to use Jquery:

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/A3m7w/)

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if ( $(window).innerWidth() < 600 ) {
     $(".div1").insertAfter(".divA");  
     $(".div2").insertAfter(".divB");
     $(".right").remove();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you have asked, but looks same. Here I am going to give some example. Hopefully it will help you. Reduce the width, you can see the effect.

**HTML**

```
<div id="n1">Div1</div>
<div id="a">DivA</div>
<div id="n1">Div2</div>
<div id="b">DivB</div>
<div id="n1">Div3</div>
<div id="c">DivC</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 #n1, #n2, #n3{
float:left;  
border:1px solid #000;
clear:left;
}
#a, #b, #c
{
float:right;
border:1px solid #000;
clear:right;
}
@media all and (max-width:400px)
{            
   #a, #b, #c
  {
    float:none;
    clear:both;
  }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2NQpH/)

Answer (score 0):

HTML/CSS solution:

Take a look at [**this article**](http://tanalin.com/en/articles/css-block-order/): explain how reorder div order by css.

Javascript/jQuery:

What you need is a "comb" solution, merging div contents.

You can use this merge function:

```
    var merge = function(divA, divB) {
      var $divA = $(divA);
      var $divB = $(divB);
      var d1Num = $divA.children().length;
      var d2Num = $divB.children().length;
      var i = 0;
      for (; i < d1Num; i+=2) { 
        var a = $divA.children().eq(i);
        var b = $divB.children().eq(0);
        b.insertAfter(a);     
      }
      if(d2Num >= d1Num) {
        d2Num = $divB.children().length;
        for (i = 0; i < d2Num; i++) { 
          var a = $divA.children().last();
          var b = $divB.children().eq(0);
          b.insertAfter(a); 
        }
      } else {
         var a = $divA.children().eq(i+1);
         var b = $divB.children().eq(0);
         b.insertAfter(a);     
      }
  }

  merge("#d1", "#d2");
```

In this way, your div could have how many child you want.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lzdz8/1/)**.